# Angularfire Query based on multiple where same column

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

Hi guys I have a question.

it is possible to double where to a query with the same column different values

```
this.afs.collection ( 'boys', ref => {
     return ref.orderBy ( 'firstName', 'asc' )
               .where ( 'place', '==', 'home')
               .where ( 'place', '==', 'school' );

boys: [
 1: {firstName:'Peter', place:'home'},
 2: {firstName:'Martha', place:'home'},
 3: {firstName:'Juan', place:'school'},
 4: {firstName:'Charles', place:'park'},
 5: {firstName:'Andrew', place:'garden'},
 6: {firstName:'Maria', place:'school'},
]
```

value expected

```
[
 2: {firstName:'Martha', place:'home'},
 1: {firstName:'Peter', place:'home'},
 3: {firstName:'Juan', place:'school'},
 6: {firstName:'Maria', place:'school'},
]
```

**The order is irrelevant**

Comment: Somehow I don’t get what you mean.  Do you want to order by first name then by place?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer really the ordering is not important, what I want is to do a search for a column that contains two or more different values, it would be something like the `SELECT IN` in sql

Comment: Is place an ordinal or a location? Can place be replaced for 1 as in the number, or is that your test data and a place will end up "College Campus"?

Comment: @cutikoI can't change the values to number, they must be text

Comment: Why those values must be text? Arent those values representing number?

Comment: @cutiko It is an example of the data, but text is stored in the database

Comment: I see the edit on the question, this discard my solution so I think you should explain more in-depth what you want to get someone help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to accomplish that in one query. But what you can do is to use two separate queries and then combine them.

Here is an example for that:

```
const resultA = this.afs.collection ( 'boys', ref => {
     return ref.orderBy ( 'firstName', 'asc' )
               .where ( 'place', '==', 'one');


const resultB = this.afs.collection ( 'boys', ref => {
     return ref.orderBy ( 'firstName', 'asc' )
               .where ( 'place', '==', 'two' );

const resultAB = combineLatest(resultA, resultB).pipe(
    map(([boysA, boysB]) => boysA.concat(boysB)));
```

Comment: This is correct, firestore doesn't support OR like operators :)